# As simple as possible template engine for embedding repeating html elements

Tags: javascript, html, include, template-engine

There are quite a few questions on this topic, but I did not find anything that I liked.

I decided to update my one-page portfolio and make it multi-page (github pages). For convenience, I would like to embed repeating 3 files head, header, footer. What can be used to do this so that it has minimal impact on performance.

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/) offers many ways to do what you're trying to do, but I think the easiest one is:

```
<body>
  
  <iframe src="./header.html"></iframe>
  
  Content.
  
  <iframe src="./footer.html"></iframe>
  
</body>
```

and the one it suggests will minimally impact performance is:

```
<body>
   <?php include "./header.html" ?>

   Content

   <?php include "./footer.html" ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to say, website on github pages, SSI or Server Side Languages are not supported.

Comment: The top one will work for you better then.